# Vertical Nav Menu That Scrolls Then Also Has A Fly Out (can only be html/css per requirements)

Tags: html, css, menu, vertical-scrolling, flyout

Hey guys full disclosure I've never used this site so sorry for the noob stuff. I'm sure I'll get better as I go.

The goal is to create a (html/css only) vertical navigation menu that will have a scrolling capabilities and fly out to the right to expand for further subjects. I've built the basics but the scroll (as well as a few other things) keeps eluding me. I've been able to get a scroll to work on the main nav but not one that is allowing me to keep the fly out working. I've included the code I have so far and a mock up of the how the nav should work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>module3</title>
</head> 
<style type="text/css">

    *{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }       


    a   {
        color:inherit;
        text-decoration: none;
        }

    ul#navmenu a:hover{
        color: #FFF;
        }   

    body
        {
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue 25 Ultra Light", Arial;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 50px;

        color: #535353;
        }

            ul#navmenu, ul.sub1, ul.sub2 {
            list-style-type: none;
            }
            ul#navmenu li {
                /*outline: 1px solid red*/
                width: 310px;
                text-align: center;
                position: relative;
                border-bottom: 0.12em dotted #ABB0B0;
                text-align: left;
            }
            ul#navmenu a {
                text-decoration: none;
                display: block;
                width: 300px;
                height: 45px;
                line-height: 45px;
                background-color: #E5E8E9;
                padding-left: 10px;
            }   
            ul#navmenu .sub1 li {

            }
            ul#navmenu .su1 a {
                margin-top: 5px;


            }
            ul#navmenu .sub2 a {
                margin-left: 10px;
                width: 500px;

            }
            ul#navmenu li:hover > a {
                background-color: #0098ba;
            }
            ul#navmenu li:hover a:hover {
                background-color: #0098ba;
            }
            ul#navmenu ul.sub1 {
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
                top: 45px;
                left: 0px;

            }
            ul#navmenu ul.sub2 {
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
                top: -92px;
                left: 300px;
                width: 800px;

            }
            ul#navmenu li:hover .sub1 {
                display: block;

            }
            ul#navmenu .sub1 li:hover .sub2 {
                display: block;

            }
            .sub2  {
                text-transform: capitalize;
                font-size: 14px;
                            }
            .button  {
                -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
                -moz-border-radius: 2px;
                border-radius: 2px;
                background-color: #f4f4e8;
                border: solid 1px #c7c7c7;  
                font-size: 14px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                color: #006792;     
                cursor: pointer; 
                -webkit-appearance: button;
                box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #c7c7c7;
            }


            .triangleTop {

                position:relative;
                left: 270px;
                top: 30px;
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
                border-right: 10px solid transparent;
                border-bottom: 10px solid #0098ba;
                border-left: 10px solid transparent;
                z-index: 2;


            }
            /* I will fix this &nbsp; business soon */
            strong {font-size: 12px;}

        </style>


<body>

<div class="triangleTop"></div> 

<ul id="navmenu">

    <li><a>lorem ipsum dolor ari</a>

            <ul class="sub1">
                <li><a href="#">litigation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">payroll</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">pensions/benefits</a>

                    <ul class="sub2">
                        <li><a href="#">PENSION AND BENEFITS<strong>HOME</strong></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span style="font-weight:bold;">SEARCH:</span>&nbsp;Law</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span style="font-weight:bold;">SEARCH:</span>&nbsp;Intellectual property</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Folk on the Delaware General Corporation Law - Welch, Turezyn and Saunders</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Folk on the Delaware General Corporation Law - Welch, Turezyn and Saunders</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Folk on the Delaware General Corporation Law - Welch, Turezyn and Saunders</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Folk on the Delaware General Corporation Law - Welch, Turezyn and Saunders</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Folk on the Delaware General Corporation Law - Welch, Turezyn and Saunders</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Folk on the Delaware General Corporation Law - Welch, Turezyn and Saunders</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Folk on the Delaware General Corporation Law - Welch, Turezyn and Saunders</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Folk on the Delaware General Corporation Law - Welch, Turezyn and Saunders</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Folk on the Delaware General Corporation Law - Welch, Turezyn and </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">product liability and insurance</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">proerty and construciton law</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Securities and corporate</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">tax law</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">transportation</a></li>

                <a class="button">Manage content collections</a>




            </ul>
        </li>



</body>
</html>

![Photo mock up from client][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIR1x.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the container's `height` and the `overflow-y: auto;` property.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wx7n0mqc/